# Blacklist IP After Using WordPress Plugin Detector?

Tags: plugins, ip

I searched a website to see what some of the plugins it is using.
I used: http://wppluginchecker.earthpeople.se/

Now when I visit the website, it looks like the CSS is missing. I have been told this has happened in the past, but it seems coincidental.

Is is possible they somehow blacklisted our IP address?

Comment: if your IP was blacklisted you wouldn't be able to load anything, not just the CSS

Comment: The site loads correct if I use a proxy or mobile phone.

Comment: It could be blacklisting then, it might not be, it's very difficult if not impossible to tell without being able to replicate, or without direct examples. e.g. what HTTP response do you get? From which domain? Does it even connect? CSS not loading in a browser could be due to many many things, including CSS actually loading but not being applied, or your specific browser. More information is needed for a conclusive answer

Comment: I believe it's common practice to take a look at a competitor's website, and see if you can find some of the wordpress related elements they have. No idea it would lead to possible blacklisting.

Answer (score 0):

Although [@webman](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/146762/webman) is correct, it is also possible that the site is loading some files from another place than their domain, and that 'another place' is blocking you.

You could determine for sure by using the Developer Tools (F12 usually) in your browser, selecting the Network tab, then reloading the page. That will show you all of the 'requests' for the page, and you can determine if there are requests that are blocked.

But I suspect that the site is broken a bit. I use this site to check theme/plugin usage: https://whatwpthemeisthat.com/ ; there are many similar sites available that you can find via the googles.

Comment: Just used the F12 developer tool. Most of the status column is showing a 403 forbidden error, some is showing a 200 OK message.

Comment: The 403 errors are probably password-protected areas, and are an indication that the web site is broken a bit. Slight possibility of some viral content on the site. Try one of the other theme/plugin checker sites, like the one I mentioned. But the problem with the site you mentioned is not your fault, but the site's fault.

Comment: Seems very coincidental the site now loads incorrect only at the location I used a theme/plugin checker.

Comment: That site is really slow in analysis, plus it makes tons of requests to the site to analyze. Very slow, and very instrusive on accessing the site. And it any info on the WP site I tested...and took 5 minutes to do their test. For that reason, I would not recommend that site. If you want a quick look at a sites' themes/plugins, then use the link I referenced in my answer. YMMV. Personal opinion of the site you referenced....